# Using own properties in CKEditor 4 plugin (upgrade from version 3)

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I was using CKEditor 3 with the jQuery Adapter, wanted to update to version 4.3.1. But I stumbled upon a `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor`.

I found the row that creates this error, but I can't find a way to fix it. I got my own CKEditor plugins and set some meta-data to the plugins as well:

MAIN.JS

```
objectWrapper.ckeditor(function(element){
     // Callback function code.
}, {
    extraPlugins: 'companySave,companyImage',
    companySave: { ... },
    companyImage: { ... },
    companyMetaData: getMataData() //extra config field
}
```

PLUGIN.JS (*companyImage*)

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'companyImage',
{
init: function( editor ) {
       ....
       editor.config.companyMetaData.doSomething() //using the extra config field
    }
}
```

In CKEditor 3 I could do pass my own object to the plugins, but in version 4 it seems I cannot. Once I define my own config fields, I got that `Illegal constructor` error.

**How can I pass my own object to plugins in CKEditor 4?**

---

BTW

```
objectWrapper.ckeditor(function(element){
     // Callback function code.
}, {
    extraPlugins: 'companySave,companyImage',
    companySave: { ... },
    companyImage: { 
       companyMetaData: getMataData() //extra config field
       ... 
    },
}
```

gives met the same error.

---

**EDIT**
Seems i can pass objects the way I described, but I can't pass jQuery objects.
So `companyMetaData: $('body')` can't be used, but `companyMetaData: {}` is no problem.

Comment: I could work around the problem by using companyMetaData: getMataData().doSomething. But if anyone does know why jQuery objects are not allowed, I am inclined to read it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is fixed in version [4.4.2](http://ckeditor.com/release/CKEditor-4.4.2) in ticket [#11478](http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/11478):

```
#11478: Fixed: Issue with passing jQuery objects to adapter configuration.
```